# Esri enterprise geodatabase migration to PostGIS/PostgreSQL using FME

Tags: postgis, fme-form, esri-geodatabase, migration, enterprise

I am trying to migrate my Esri enterprise geodatabase (10.2.2) on MSSQL server 2012 to PostGIS version 2.0/PostgreSQL version 9.4 using trial version of FME. I am getting the following errors;

bulk copy failed on table 'table name' using delimiter ':'. Error was Error column has Z dimension but geometry doesnot Context: Copy 'table name', line 1, column geom:''

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?
[image: dimensionextractor]
[image: datainspector feature attribute]
[image: tester]
[image: error]

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post to include a screenshot of your workspace?

Comment: thanks @Fezter. i have added an image of my workspace.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify an actual version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: postgis 2.0/postgresql 9.4 @Vince

Comment: Both are quite old; 9.4 slated for retirement, and 2.0 has exceeded end-of-life by three releases.

Comment: thanks for the info@vince. i am just at the testing phase as of now. i will use the latest and stable versions in the final one.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious thing to me about the log is the message **"Column has Z dimension, but geometry does not"**. That seems to imply that the actual issue is 2D geometry being written to a 3D geometry column.

There are three ways I can see this occurring, one of which relates to a known issue.

1: If your data is 2D, but you're writing to an existing table that already has a 3D geometry column, then the error would occur. To resolve this add a Z value to all features. You'd do this with the 3DForcer transformer. Even if the elevation is set to zero, it would still solve the problem. I suspect this might be the issue if you're writing to a table that already existed, rather than have FME create it.

2: If the table doesn't already exist, and you are creating it with FME, then I suspect the problem is with this known issue. Basically, the scenario is that your source data is 2D with measures, and FME misinterprets the measures and tries to create a 3D table.

I can see two solutions to that scenario. Firstly - if you don't want the measures - use a MeasureRemover transformer to get rid of them before writing the data. Secondly - if you do want the measures - create the table manually in PostGIS rather than have FME create it. That way you can set it up as 2D+measures, and FME will happily write to it.

3: One other possibility surrounds the Table Handling parameter. This can be set up to write to an existing table, create a new table if it doesn't already exist, drop and (re)create an existing table, or truncate an existing table. If - for example - you wrote 3D data and asked FME to create the table, then it would create a 3D geometry column. But if you then switched the data to a 2D version, and left the Table Handling as "Create if Needed" then FME would not drop or re-create the table, but keep the 3D version and try to write 2D data to it, thus erroring out.

The solution would be to set Table Handling to Drop and Create. You would also need to do that in scenario 2 above, after using the MeasureRemover transformer, to create the proper geometry column type.

Of course there's always the possibility that there is some other issue going on, but basically the 3DForcer or MeasureRemover transformers are what I'd try first (remembering to drop/recreate the table as necessary).

Comment: thanks@Mark Ireland. Setting Table Handling to Drop and Create solved my problem.thanks again.

Comment: How do i create a 3d table in postgis? some of my data has elevation (the datatype for the points in  arcmap attribute table shows shape:pointZ ).

Comment: I believe that as long as the data has a z value (or at least the first feature to arrive at the writer does) then FME will create a 3d table. If you find that's not the case, let me know and I can investigate some more.

Comment: My data is from arcsde enterprise geodatabase. The point data has geometry type as point Z. FME is giving the error:Column has Z dimension but  geometry doesnot context. i have added a screenshot from my arcmap and FME in my question. thanks

Comment: Can you read the source data into the FME Data Inspector, query a feature, and provide a screenshot of the Feature Information window? It could be that FME isn't reading it as 3D for some reason. Another way to test your data would be to use a combination of DimensionExtractor and Tester transformer - extract the dimension with the DimensionExtractor (ie 2d or 3d) and then test for those values in the Tester. I'm thinking that maybe the first feature is 3D but one or more subsequent features isn't.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Ireland. i have added the screenshots using dimesion Extractor and tester. it shows that my data is 3D but i am still unable to write to postgis(drop and create option). when i converted to 2D using 2DForcer transformer, i was able to write to postgis!

Comment: I'm checking with the developers at Safe and I'll get back to you. Apologies for the inconvenience this is causing. It's got me stumped how this is happening.

Comment: It seems a colleague of mine posted a possible solution to this on the FME Knowledgebase recently. See: https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/89491/converting-from-esri-enterprise-geodatabase-on-mss.html - I'm hoping you aren't the same user! In short, if you turn off the bulk insert parameter, you might get a more useful error message from postgres.